# Plot a Neural Net Curve Using neuralnet and ROCR package

Tags: r, neural-network, classification, roc

Here I have a classification task and I need to use neuralnet and ROCR packages. The problem is that I got the error messages when I use prediction function.

Here is my code:

```
#load packages
require(neuralnet)
library(ROCR)

#create data set 
train<-read.table(file="train.txt",header=TRUE,sep=",")
test<- read.table(file="test.txt",header=TRUE,sep=",")

#build model and make predictions 
nn.sag <- neuralnet(Type ~ Area+Perimeter+Compactness+Length+Width+Asymmetry+Groove, data = train, hidden = 5, algorithm = "sag", err.fct = "sse", linear.output = FALSE)

prob = compute(nn.sag, test[, -ncol(test)] )
prob.result <- prob$net.result

nn.pred = prediction(prob.result, test$Type)
pref <- performance(nn.pred, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(pref)
```

And here I got the error message for the 'prediction' function: 
'$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors'

The dataset looks like (only training dataset here):

```
Area,Perimeter,Compactness,Length,Width,Asymmetry,Groove,Type
14.8,14.52,0.8823,5.656,3.288,3.112,5.309,1
14.79,14.52,0.8819,5.545,3.291,2.704,5.111,1
14.99,14.56,0.8883,5.57,3.377,2.958,5.175,1
19.14,16.61,0.8722,6.259,3.737,6.682,6.053,0
15.69,14.75,0.9058,5.527,3.514,1.599,5.046,1
14.11,14.26,0.8722,5.52,3.168,2.688,5.219,1
13.16,13.55,0.9009,5.138,3.201,2.461,4.783,1
16.16,15.33,0.8644,5.845,3.395,4.266,5.795,0
15.01,14.76,0.8657,5.789,3.245,1.791,5.001,1
14.11,14.1,0.8911,5.42,3.302,2.7,5,1
17.98,15.85,0.8993,5.979,3.687,2.257,5.919,0
21.18,17.21,0.8989,6.573,4.033,5.78,6.231,0
14.29,14.09,0.905,5.291,3.337,2.699,4.825,1
14.59,14.28,0.8993,5.351,3.333,4.185,4.781,1
11.42,12.86,0.8683,5.008,2.85,2.7,4.607,1
12.11,13.47,0.8392,5.159,3.032,1.502,4.519,1
15.6,15.11,0.858,5.832,3.286,2.725,5.752,0
15.38,14.66,0.899,5.477,3.465,3.6,5.439,0
18.94,16.49,0.875,6.445,3.639,5.064,6.362,0
12.36,13.19,0.8923,5.076,3.042,3.22,4.605,1
14.01,14.29,0.8625,5.609,3.158,2.217,5.132,1
17.12,15.55,0.8892,5.85,3.566,2.858,5.746,0
15.78,14.91,0.8923,5.674,3.434,5.593,5.136,1
16.19,15.16,0.8849,5.833,3.421,0.903,5.307,1
14.43,14.4,0.8751,5.585,3.272,3.975,5.144,1
13.8,14.04,0.8794,5.376,3.155,1.56,4.961,1
14.46,14.35,0.8818,5.388,3.377,2.802,5.044,1
18.59,16.05,0.9066,6.037,3.86,6.001,5.877,0
18.75,16.18,0.8999,6.111,3.869,4.188,5.992,0
15.49,14.94,0.8724,5.757,3.371,3.412,5.228,1
12.73,13.75,0.8458,5.412,2.882,3.533,5.067,1
13.5,13.85,0.8852,5.351,3.158,2.249,5.176,1
14.38,14.21,0.8951,5.386,3.312,2.462,4.956,1
14.86,14.67,0.8676,5.678,3.258,2.129,5.351,1
18.45,16.12,0.8921,6.107,3.769,2.235,5.794,0
17.32,15.91,0.8599,6.064,3.403,3.824,5.922,0
20.2,16.89,0.8894,6.285,3.864,5.173,6.187,0
20.03,16.9,0.8811,6.493,3.857,3.063,6.32,0
18.14,16.12,0.8772,6.059,3.563,3.619,6.011,0
13.99,13.83,0.9183,5.119,3.383,5.234,4.781,1
15.57,15.15,0.8527,5.92,3.231,2.64,5.879,0
16.2,15.27,0.8734,5.826,3.464,2.823,5.527,1
20.97,17.25,0.8859,6.563,3.991,4.677,6.316,0
14.16,14.4,0.8584,5.658,3.129,3.072,5.176,1
13.45,14.02,0.8604,5.516,3.065,3.531,5.097,1
15.5,14.86,0.882,5.877,3.396,4.711,5.528,1
16.77,15.62,0.8638,5.927,3.438,4.92,5.795,0
12.74,13.67,0.8564,5.395,2.956,2.504,4.869,1
14.88,14.57,0.8811,5.554,3.333,1.018,4.956,1
14.28,14.17,0.8944,5.397,3.298,6.685,5.001,1
14.34,14.37,0.8726,5.63,3.19,1.313,5.15,1
14.03,14.16,0.8796,5.438,3.201,1.717,5.001,1
19.11,16.26,0.9081,6.154,3.93,2.936,6.079,0
14.52,14.6,0.8557,5.741,3.113,1.481,5.487,1
18.43,15.97,0.9077,5.98,3.771,2.984,5.905,0
18.81,16.29,0.8906,6.272,3.693,3.237,6.053,0
13.78,14.06,0.8759,5.479,3.156,3.136,4.872,1
14.69,14.49,0.8799,5.563,3.259,3.586,5.219,1
18.85,16.17,0.9056,6.152,3.806,2.843,6.2,0
12.88,13.5,0.8879,5.139,3.119,2.352,4.607,1
12.78,13.57,0.8716,5.262,3.026,1.176,4.782,1
14.33,14.28,0.8831,5.504,3.199,3.328,5.224,1
19.46,16.5,0.8985,6.113,3.892,4.308,6.009,0
19.38,16.72,0.8716,6.303,3.791,3.678,5.965,0
15.26,14.85,0.8696,5.714,3.242,4.543,5.314,1
20.24,16.91,0.8897,6.315,3.962,5.901,6.188,0
19.94,16.92,0.8752,6.675,3.763,3.252,6.55,0
20.71,17.23,0.8763,6.579,3.814,4.451,6.451,0
16.17,15.38,0.8588,5.762,3.387,4.286,5.703,0
13.02,13.76,0.8641,5.395,3.026,3.373,4.825,1
16.53,15.34,0.8823,5.875,3.467,5.532,5.88,0
13.89,14.02,0.888,5.439,3.199,3.986,4.738,1
18.98,16.57,0.8687,6.449,3.552,2.144,6.453,0
17.08,15.38,0.9079,5.832,3.683,2.956,5.484,1
15.03,14.77,0.8658,5.702,3.212,1.933,5.439,1
16.14,14.99,0.9034,5.658,3.562,1.355,5.175,1
18.65,16.41,0.8698,6.285,3.594,4.391,6.102,0
20.1,16.99,0.8746,6.581,3.785,1.955,6.449,0
17.99,15.86,0.8992,5.89,3.694,2.068,5.837,0
15.88,14.9,0.8988,5.618,3.507,0.7651,5.091,1
13.22,13.84,0.868,5.395,3.07,4.157,5.088,1
18.3,15.89,0.9108,5.979,3.755,2.837,5.962,0
19.51,16.71,0.878,6.366,3.801,2.962,6.185,0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `prediction()` function is available in both neuralnet and ROCR package in R. So do not load both packages together. First load neuralnet, train your model and then detach it using `detach()` and then load ROCR package. Try following code:

```
#load packages
require(neuralnet)

#create data set 
train<-read.table(file="train.txt",header=TRUE,sep=",")
test<- read.table(file="test.txt",header=TRUE,sep=",")

#build model and make predictions 
nn.sag <- neuralnet(Type ~ Area+Perimeter+Compactness+Length+Width+Asymmetry+Groove, data = train, hidden = 5, algorithm = "sag", err.fct = "sse", linear.output = FALSE)

prob = compute(nn.sag, test[, -ncol(test)] )
prob.result <- prob$net.result

detach(package:neuralnet,unload = T)

library(ROCR)
nn.pred = prediction(prob.result, test$Type)
pref <- performance(nn.pred, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(pref)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply use `ROCR::prediction(prediction(prob.result, test$Type))`

For selecting the right package.